# Wifi Connection Problems

Tags: hardware

I'm having a WiFi sharing problem.

I'm using my ipad air as a hotspot for my mac osx leporad (which has a airport card). My mac recognizes my ipad but when I click on it nothing happens. so I went to system presences and tried to add a network there and when I get to enter your password, I do that and it says connection timed out or password invaild......(Which I know the password it right)

If my mac can detect my ipad hotspot why won't my mac connect to it?????
Anyone please help me! Also I have a Mac OS X 10.5

Thankx

Answer (score 1):

To set up a hot spot on your iPad, start by opening Settings and navigating to General > Network. (Note: you will need to have the Cellular Data connection turned on.)

You can set up your personal hot spot by tapping on the giant setup button, which will **check with your carrier to see if the feature is supported**, and if it is, allow you to turn the hot spot on. If your carrier doesn't support it, you'll get an alert telling you as much.

Enter a password that has to be minimum 8 characters long.

Comment: Okay. I have my ipad already on a hotspot. I'am just trying to figure out how to connect my mac to it.

Comment: Just making sure you have a type of network provider that allows you to share the connection. Double check the password settings on iPad.

Comment: Okay. Im trying that now.

Comment: didnt work. I cant change password on ipad.

Comment: You can change your Wi-Fi password by tapping Settings > Personal Hotspot or Settings > Cellular > Personal Hotspot and then tapping the Wi-Fi password.